# How do I check the type of a node in cypher?

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I have a graph with three node types: NodeX, NodeY, and NodeZ

I have the this cypher query:

```
MATCH (x:NodeX)-[*]->(d)  
WHERE x.Name = 'pqr'  
RETURN x,d;
```

Here (d) may could be either NodeY or NodeZ.
I'm looking to handle different nodetypes separately. Something like:

```
MATCH (x:NodeX)-[*]->(d)  
WHERE x.Name = 'pqr'  
WITH d
CASE WHEN typeof(d)=NodeY THEN {MATCH (y:NodeY)-[*]-(z:NodeZ)}
     WHEN typeof(d)=NodeZ THEN {MATCH (z:NodeZ)-[*]-(y:NodeY)}
RETURN y,z
```

`y` and `z` correspond to `d`. Is this possible to do so?

Comment: Also, are `y` and/or `z` supposed to correspond to `d`? Can you clarify what it is you are trying to do?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Nodes have "labels", not "types" (the latter term only applies to relationships).

To get the labels of a node, you can use the `LABELS()` function. So, to test if node `n` has the label `Foo`, you can do something like this in Cypher:

```
CASE WHEN 'Foo' IN LABELS(n) THEN ...
```

However, the `CASE` clause cannot contain a `MATCH` clause.

[EDITED]

In your specific case, something like this query (which assumes that, as you said, the only labels possible for `d` are `NodeY` and `NodeZ`) may work:

```
MATCH (x:NodeX)-[*]->(d)
WHERE x.Name = 'pqr'  
WITH d, CASE WHEN 'NodeY' IN LABELS(d) THEN 'NodeZ' ELSE 'NodeY' END AS otherLabel
MATCH (d)-[*]-(other)
WHERE otherLabel IN LABELS(other)
RETURN d, other;
```